# 2D clip in OpenGL

Tags: opengl

I have a question  about clipping in OpenGL. So I have a small viewport and I want to render one part of a large image.  If I draw a large image like

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE)

glColor3f(1,1,1)

glTexCoord2f(0,height)
glVertex2f(0,0)

glTexdoord2f(width,height)
glVertex2f(width,0)

glTexCoord2f(width,0)
glVertex2f(width,height)

glTexCoord(0,0)
glVertex2f(0,height)
```

The width and height is **the size of the image(texture), which is much larger than the viewport.**

My question is: Is OpenGL going to firstly clip the rectangle with respect to the size of viewport and then draw, or firstly render the whole image and then clip?

Answer (score 1):

It will first clip the geometry, then draw. More specifically, OpenGL does all the geometry processing before going down to render individual framebuffer elements (pixels). Here's a relevant quote from the 3.3 GL spec (Section 2.4):

> The final resulting primitives are clipped to a viewing volume in
>   preparation for the next stage, rasterization. The rasterizer produces
>   a series of framebuffer addresses and values using a two-dimensional
>   description of a point, line segment, or polygon.

Comment: Thanks, so the speed of rendering won't be affected by the size of image because it is clipped to the viewport.

Comment: @YanLi: Note that this is only what the specification says will happen. Drivers can implement it however they want, so long as the results are identical. This is the "as if" rules: drivers implement it "as if" it happened this way.